# WebSQL - Capacity

Tags: ios, cordova, web-sql

I have a PhoneGap app on iOS using a WebSQL database.  In some places I'm reading that the storage capacity is 5MB and in others I'm reading it's 50MB, can someone clear this up for me?  Also I'm planning on storing base64 images inside the database.  Should I do this or should I write the images to the filesystem instead to save space in the db?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but during my testing on WebSQL on iOS I found that the limit is 50MB (if you just use the WebSQL without plugins).

I created a plugin to work around this limit for storage.

https://github.com/Thinkwise/cordova-plugin-update-quota

Answer (score 0):

It will works fine in ios but it won't work in blackberry or windows mobile .

check this one,

http://www.steveworkman.com/html5-2/standards/2011/the-limitations-of-websql-and-offline-apps/

Comment: I know it works, I'm just talking about the storage capacity.  What is the MB limit?

Comment: I read the information on the link you provided, it still does not give me a clear limit.  It only talks about Chrome.  I just want this basic question answered:  What is the MB limit for websql using PhoneGap and iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

Limit for localstorage is 5MB and WebSql is 50MB in iOS. If you use Sqlite plugin with your phonegap app, database size can be increased.